# Issue with Shine MP3 Encoder on Alchemy

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5, alchemy

I have been trying to use the "Shine MP3 Encoder on Alchemy" in my action script [file](http://code.google.com/p/flash-kikko/):

```
import fr.kikko.lab.ShineMP3Encoder
```

But always seems to get 2 errors:

> 1180: Call to a possible undefined method CLibInit
>
> 1172: Definition cmodule.shine:ClibInit could not be found

Could anybody tells me what I am doing wrong or how to sort these issues?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem.

In order to remedy it, in my fla I went to File -> ActionScript Settings -> Library Path -> Clicked the "Browse to SWC" icon and added the swc:

[image: SWC]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the .swc (shineMP3_alchemy.swc) added to your build path.

Comment: I have this same problem, @Eran, I'm very new to flash, how do I add the .swc to my project build path?

Comment: http://flexnflex.wordpress.com/2009/07/22/steps-using-swc-files-in-your-flex-projects/